# Testing Failure Scenarios with Webdriverio

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, webdriver.io

I may be approaching this the wrong way, but is it possible to mock http call failures (http status of 500) by intercepting a http request for a specific endpoint?

I am trying to test a UI flow that only occurs with a 500 response.  Is this possible, or should I look into alternate approaches of making a response 500?

Comment: On what layer you are testing? UI or API? Both will have different verification assertions.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal These tests are running on the UI layer - integrating with API's that I do not own.

Comment: Then don't verify response codes directly but assert the corresponding behavior in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use [Feature Flags](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html).

With these, you can, at compiling time, pick blocks of code, depending on configuration.

For instance (pseudo-code):

```
def request_handler(request):
    #ifdef TESTING_MODE
    return HTTP(500);
    #endinf
    .... production code...
```

TESTING_MODE variable would be set in a kind of config.json file or during the building, with Jenkins, e.g.

Different stacks would have its own syntax and approaches, but the idea is the same.